# MySQL UNIQUE Constraint with a condition

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a unique index constraint for two columns (id_1 and id_2) with the following condition:
If two different rows have the same value in the id_2 column, their values in the id_1 column must also be the same.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no declarative constraint to support such a restriction. The scenario you describe does not satisfy the requirements for a unique constraint.  (You can create the constraint, but you won't be able to add more than one row with identical values for id_1 and id_2.

If your intent is to reject an insert or an update based on this restriction, you might be able to accomplish this with a row-level trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by building a query that checks these rows and integrate it in a trigger. You won't be able to do that with a constraint and certainly not with a unique constraint. A unique constraint forces rows to have unique values. That means that for the field or fields in the constraint no two rows can have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. A unique constraint on `id_1` and `id_2` will force each row to have a different (*unique*) combination of `id_1` and `id_2`. That's the exact opposite of what you are describing.

You could possibly enforce your requirement by using a trigger, but given the small amount of information provided by you, I can't say if it would be the best solution.

A composite foreign key could also be the solution, but I don't know what `id_1` and `id_2` refer to, so it's hard to say, really.